# How would you store contacts in Azure Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Each user of my system can have contacts. Each contact has details like Name, Address, Email, Phone, etc.

Do you think is a good idea to store this contacts in Azure Tables? I am worried about the following:

- How do I search for a specific field (like Email or Phone)?
- How do I get only the contacts belonging to a specific user?
- How do I sort the contacts by a field?

Answer (score 1):

I think that contacts could be a good candidate for storing in Table Storage - but only if you can partition on the owning person and never really need to search or aggregate across multiple owning users.

One possible design for this is:

- store the contacts once with the owning user as partition key and some unique field for row key, but with the fields as columns within each row.

> How do I search for a specific field (like Email or Phone)?

- You can then ask table storage to search within a partition - it will then do a scan within that partition - which shouldn't be particularly large or slow for any single partition.

> How do I get only the contacts belonging to a specific user?

- This is just a simple query by partition key only

> How do I sort the contacts by a field?

- All results from table storage are sorted by (partitionkey, rowkey) so to sort the contacts for a user, you'll need to query for all of them, and then sort them within your web or worker role.

---

Other designs are, of course, possible -

e.g. you could store each contact in multiple rows in multiple tables - this would then allow you to have pre-formed sort orders within the table storage.

e.g. you could use separate tables instead of separate partitionkeys for each user - this has the advantage that when you delete a user, you can delete the entire table belonging to that user.

---

Note... while it's possible to use table storage for this... actually I almost always seem to end up back in SQL Azure at the moment - it's just so much more powerful and predictable (IMO). When the team deliver secondary indexing, then I might be tempted to use it for more of my data.

Comment: While this answers the major part of the question it leaves a huge part open - performance. Never search inside your objects. Condiser them serialized and unknowm to you until you deserialize them back. Searches by parition key are fast as that is indexed... Keep that in mind!

Comment: I agree you need to be careful about performance, Anze - but don't agree with "never search inside your objects". Assuming that the number of contacts per partition is small (e.g. <1000) and assuming that searches in this case will always specify a single partition key, then I think searching by fields should give acceptable performance here.